# How to strip HTML from a field in drupal views

Tags: sql-server, drupal, view

I am trying to add a function to that strips the html from a field in drupal views. I found a function for sql server called "udf_StripHTML" that does that.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/16/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-strip-html-parse-html-no-regular-expression/

I am using the following code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function cviews_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
    // Add a strip html tags from content.
    $fields = array('field_data_body.body_value');

    foreach ($query->where as $key1 => $value) {
        foreach ($value['conditions'] as $key2 => $coditions) {
          if (in_array($coditions['field'], $fields)) {
            $query->where[$key1]['conditions'][$key2]['field'] = 'dbo.udf_StripHTML(' . $coditions['field'] . ')';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When views module converts the query object to a string the field become
from:
     'dbo.udf_StripHTML(field_data_body.body_value)';

to:
     [dbo].[udf_StripHTMLfield_data_body.body_value]

My question is, how can I add a function there?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

You are going way too deep here friend.  I'm going to assume that you're using Drupal 7, but for Drupal 8 this should be similar (since views is in core for both).

A few things about your approach:

- That function is a *user defined function* which means that it needs to be defined at a much lower-level (in the SQL database) *before you can use it in your query*.
- This is a red-herring approach, however, because you don't need to even touch the SQL to accomplish what you want (you can do this with PHP with [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)!)
- You don't need a query alter hook here (we don't need to go to the database to do this).  You could do this with one of the ***preprocess or field hooks*** from the [field API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/group/field/7.x) or the [views API](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/7.x-3.x) using the function linked in my previous point.
- Even better, **you don't even have to touch the code to accomplish this**.  You can do it ***right in the Drupal UI***.

Under the field settings for the view, select **rewrite results** and then **Strip HTML tags**.  Presto, no more HTML tags in that field.

[image: Views UI, image source: https://www.drupal.org/node/750172]
Image source: https://www.drupal.org/node/750172

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a way to solve my problem. Checking the "Strip HTML tags" option will strip the html tags from the field and I need to do it on the filter. So I noticed that if I use operator "formula" I can get what I want. Here is the code:

$query->where[$key1]['conditions'][$key2]['field'] = 'dbo.udf_StripHTML(' . $coditions['field'] . ')';
$query->where[$key1]['conditions'][$key2]['operator'] ='formula ';
$query->where[$key1]['conditions'][$key2]['value'] = array();

Comment: Okay.  I'm just not sure without looking at the code in action.  It just seems to me that this would be doable without touching the SQL query at all (see my third point).  Filters can be adjusted in php as well without touching the SQL (Google *filter groups in Drupal* or *exposed filters Drupal*).  Either way, there is more than one way to skin a cat and if it works, it works ;)  If you find my answer helpful, can please mark it as accepted.  [See why accepting an answer is important](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
// Traverse through the 'where' part of the query.
foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
   foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {

      if (in_array($condition['field'], $fields)) {
         $value = $condition['value'];
         $field = $condition['field'];

         $condition = array(
           'value' => array(),
           'field' => t('dbo.udf_StripHTML(!field) like \'@value\'', array(
           '!field' => $field,
           '@value' => $value)),
           'operator' => 'formula',);
      }
   }
}
```